# Laravel can not display image

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload

trying to upload an image through a post Form:
this is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title'=>'required',
        'content'=>'required',
        'image'=>'required',
        'description'=>'required'

    ]);

   $image = $request->image->store('images');


    Post::create([
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'content' => $request->input('content'),
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'image' => $image

    ]);

    return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('success', 'Posts Submitted successfully');
}
```

I used : php artisan storage:link which generated a folder named images in public directory: Absolute path is:
C:\xampp\htdocs\blogPholio\public\storage\images\KWDKRrty2ijXjrgrismvyiV4k6UAQNrFogJl9W2f.jpeg

in my blade I am trying to show image through/:

```
                                     <img src="{{Storage::url($post->image)}}">
```

My form in the create blade looks like:

```
 <form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf


                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <strong>Image:</strong>
                                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" placeholder="upload:">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Thanksa lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src="{{asset(Storage::disk('local')->url($post->image))}}"/>
```